# Get currently logged in user on remote PC without admin rights on that PC

Tags: windows, rdp

Is there a simple way (ie DOS command?) to get the name of the currently logged in user (if any) on another PC on my LAN?

I've googled a few but I'm getting Access Denied messages. I don't have admin rights on the PC I want to check, so I assume that's why.

The reason is that I share a username with someone else and when I RDP into the PC it kicks them off without warning if they are already on - as we have same name, I don't get told they are already logged on and don't have the chance to abort connection.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: The actual problem here is sharing a username with someone else; this is what you need to fix.

Comment: Yes, I agree it's not best practice. Unfortunately I'm subject to the whims of the IT Director on this. Normally he'd never allow 2 users with the same login, but for some reason he wants to do it this way...

Comment: Without access rights to query logged on users, you cannot query for lor logged on users.

Comment: That would be a huge security hole if it were possible.    I can not think of one good reason to have two users with the same credentials, but I can think of a few sketchy ones.

Comment: OK guys, fair enough, I'll try to reason with the IT Director. Thanks for your comments.